# SDA1 almost full. What do i do?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

Ive been using my ubuntu 14.4 system for awhile now.Its just Ubuntu,i havent installed it along any other os.learning as I go. Ive been doing allot of updating removing and downloading. So much so that I downloaded "Bleachbit" to keep the system clean. I get anywhere from just a few files cleaned to ,at one point, 6000+ files cleaned. Just did it again while typing and got another 4075 cleaned.

I have one SSD 240gig that Ubuntu is on and two 2TB drives for storage.Ive been reading some posts and decided to pull up "system monitor" to see what it had to say. well, i only see one of the 2tb drives,yet i can access them both from the sidebar.My main problem is the SSD, specifically SDA1 (7.7gig),its almost full. SDA6 (212.5gig) is empty.I thought I set up a 8gig partition for the swap but i dont see it.IM guessing sda1 is the root partition? When I installed this I did it from a youtube video and followed the guys steps so i dont even remember what or why i partitioned the way i did. dumb,i know.... My question is how can i see all the partitions and/or monitor them.

[image]

What do I need to do about sda1 being 86% full? Is there a way to repartition it? Do i need to move the root files? What do you do in this situation? any help would be greatly appreciated.Its been so difficult just getting this far, i really dont want to do a fresh install..ok, couldnt post a pic so i added it the best i could in a comment...

Comment: `sda1` is your EFI or boot partition. It's weird that it's almost full. If you want to look at all of your partitions, search for Gparted in Unity Dash.

Comment: Here's a link to [Gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/), try it like Zacharee1 said to see if you can better understand how your disks/partitions are being used. If you still don't get it perhaps add a screenshot of the output for /dev/sda and maybe someone else can explain it to you.

Comment: Thank you all. ill do that right now. and ill get the screen shot. shouldnt be long(if the keyboard and mouse stop freezing).

Comment: ok, i dont have enough point to post an image. ill just have to list it here as best i can.hope it helps you guys...

Comment: /dev/sda1      ext3     /      7.45gib        6.17gib    1.28g boot                             /dev/sda2        extended          216.12gib    --           --                                      /dev/sda5        linux-swap        14.9gib       4.00kib       14.90gib                   /dev/sda6        ext3     /home     201.22gib     4.78gib       196.44gib

Comment: thanks. heres the link i found. i think its the right one...http://imgur.com/UtoSUTY

Comment: ok thanks. ill have to wait till i get some blank media to do a backup and burn a live dvd.i hope this works.i saw in gparted the option to resize. why would i need to do it from a live dvd?does sda1 usually fill up like that or is something not right and im just adding space?

Comment: Trying to resize the `/` partition while Ubuntu is running from is like trying to change the tire of a car while driving it. Nobody can do it.

Comment: Thanks, just didnt think about partitioning a drive while it was in use, guess the car tire analogy works....went to the "How to resize partitions" and tried that per the instructions. the pic at the beginning of this post shows the problem stated in that how to...it seems i cant resize unless i have free space both before and after the partition that needs resizing.since i dont,im back to the original question...what do i need to do???????

Answer (score 0):

Since you have /home and / as different partitions, you still have /tmp that is part of / and that could be filling up.  Check /tmp, or delete everything in /tmp

Comment: Everything that Linux does is written into a temp file.   The minimum recommended size for Ubuntu 14.04 is 5GB, which does not leave a lot of space for anything else.  If you can, try moving /tmp to a larger partition.

Comment: just went to files-devices-computer-tmp file folder and its empty. i think bleachbit is set up to clean that folder out.

Comment: Try from a terminal, `ls -al /tmp`  You can also try `du -h --max-depth=1 /` and it will show you the size of all your folders.

Comment: just tried it. didnt see anything for "tmp"  just "/proc"  ,  "/user" and   "/ "     ...... what i do see is the rest (Looks like a hundred or so)  saying "cannot read directory" or "cannot access".

Comment: Sorry, run `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /` from the terminal

Comment: You might want to look into if you have a lot of old kernels still installed.  Look in the /usr/src folder and see.  Check what the size of those folders are in there by doing `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /usr`

Comment: Thanks Terrance......in the /usr/src folder i see 6 separate folders for generic linux headers,i think different versions? and one folder for fglrx-core. they all seem to be just a few mb each. the largest was about 64mb. heres a link to the terminal with the search you suggested...http://i.imgur.com/ZRefjeK.png

Comment: You can remove the old kernels which will free up a little space.  From terminal type in `uname -a` which will show what kernel you are using presently.   Write it down or something so you remember.  Next, see which ones are installed by typing in `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image`.  I would recommend keeping the newest 2 kernels at least, but you can remove older kernels by typing in `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.xx.x-xx-generic` to remove the extra kernels.

Comment: Or an easier line to keep the newest kernel, but get rid of all others freeing up space `dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge`