# can i add space to sda1 boot from sda2 extended

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

I tried getting help in another post 
(SDA1 almost full. What do i do? [duplicate])
and was told it was a duplicate.everyone was helpful and i tried the suggestions as well as going to a post on how to partition in gparted.i found that i am not able to resize sda1 because there is no free space either behind or in front of it.thats assuming im understanding what it was i was reading.the picture of is in the above mentioned post. i do remember reading others suggesting "moving" partitions or adding space by (i think) partioniing free space and setting it up somehow to match the boot partition? does that sound right.my boot has under 2gigs left and still filling up.any ideas? thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back to the Gparted image in your old question [SDA1 almost full. What do i do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611741/sda1-almost-full-what-do-i-do)

[image]

These are the steps to increase the size of `sda1`:

**Step 1:** Backup your data to an external medium.

**Step 2:** Boot from the Live DVD/USB and use the **Try Ubuntu without installing** option.

**Disable Swap:** Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Then open Gparted. Make sure the correct drive is selected at the top right corner.

**Step 3:** Select `sda6` Make sure you have not selected the whole of `sda2`. And right click on it. From the context menu select **Resize/Move**. Drag the right edge with a black triangle to the left to make it smaller until you have created enough empty space you need for `sda`.

**Step 4:** This is a little tougher. Now select `sda2` and repeat the same process and shrink `sda2` as far as possible.

**Step 5** Using the **Resize/Move** menu, move `sda2` all the way to the right. This will create empty space to the right of `sda1`.

**Step 6:** Using the **Resize/Move** menu on `sda1` expand it to fill up the empty space.

**Step 7:** Use the Green check mark button to apply all the changes. And wait a long time till everything is done.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much.im going to try this tomorrow as i need the computer today.taking it step by step like this is a real help to me.ill be sure to let you know how it goes.i do have a question...when i was playing around from the live cd and in gparted i would get a message about possible damage. is this a generic message or is there a real possibility ill be reinstalling from scratch *shutter*? again, thank you so very much~

Comment: ok ,thank you. ill look at some posts on backing up the system :)

Comment: ok, well ive been trying to get this to work and been reading other posts. installed clonezilla and backed up. steps 1 thru 4 worked good,no probs. step 5 however is where im stopped. i cant move sda2.everything is unmounted and the key icons are gone.had to do "swapoff". doing all this work from a live ubuntu cd. no mstter what i do i cant move anything inside of sda2. any ideas?

Comment: ok,finally, i think im getting somewhere. it took awhile and ill add a link to a pic of the new partitions. i ended up dragging from the righ and then from the left.this was the only way i could get an unallocated space to go next to sda1. well, now i have a 43.94gig space (sda6) unallocated on the far right. now i have to figure out how to merge sda5 and sda6 into back into one space.is that possible?

Comment: heres the link to the image: http://imgur.com/yQZDgUg

Comment: i looked for where to do that for you. i dont see where to mark the answer. if you can tell me where it is,ill be more than happy to do that. thanks again~