# How to shuffle partitions without massive copying

Tags: grub2, partitioning, gparted

Here is my problem. I have a lot of partitions for different systems and I just copied my entire hard disc to a bigger one. So I find myself in this situation:

PRIMARY-1 PRIMARY-2 PRIMARY-3 [EXTENDED-1 EXTENDED-2 etc etc] -free space-

I want to make PRIMARY-3 bigger so the idea is to free up EXTENDED-1 and then make that space appear as a gap before the extended partition. But I think that is the hard part - it effectively means moving the base of the extended partition up while moving all the contents of the extended area down by the same amount.

Is there an easy/safe way to do this?

Comment: See the answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/613551/can-i-add-space-to-sda1-boot-from-sda2-extended